# Merge 2 class arrays in a collection view

Tags: arrays, swift3, uicollectionview, xcode8

How can I merge 2 class arrays in a collection view? I have managed to display 2 arrays but how can I make them intertwine and append according to there postDate?

Below I have a photoPosts array and a videoPosts array and I am currently using the following method. But this only displays one array after another. Thanks in advance

```
var photoPosts = [photoPost]()
var videoPosts = [videoPost]()

func retrieveData(){
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("videoPost").child(uid)
        ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            let dictionary = videoPost(snapshot: snapshot)
            self.videoPosts.append(dictionary)
             self.videoPosts.sort(by: { (p1, p2) -> Bool in
              return p1.postDate?.compare(p2.postDate!) == .orderedDescending
                })
 })
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("photoPost").child(uid)
        ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            let dictionary = photoPost(snapshot: snapshot)
            self. photoPosts.append(dictionary)
                self.posts.sort(by: { (p1, p2) -> Bool in
                    return p1.postDate?.compare(p2.postDate!) == .orderedDescending
                })
})
 self.newsfeedCollectionView?.reloadData()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
 return videoPosts.count + photoPosts.count
}
       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {         
                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! newsfeedCollectionViewCell
             if indexPath.item < photoPosts.count {
                cell. photoPost = photoPosts[indexPath.item]
               } else {
                 cell.videoPost = videoPosts[indexPath.item-photoPosts.count]
                 }
                return cell
                }
```

updated

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("videoPost").child(user.uid!)
        ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if snapshot.exists() {

                print(snapshot)
                let array:NSArray = snapshot.children.allObjects as NSArray
                for child in array {
                    let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                    let dictionary = videoPost(snapshot: snapshot)
                    self.arrayPosts.add(dictionary)
                }
            }

            let ref1 = Database.database().reference().child("photoPost").child(user.uid!)
            ref1.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                if snapshot.exists() {
                    let array:NSArray = snapshot.children.allObjects as NSArray
                    for child in array {
                        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                        let dictionary = photoPost(snapshot: snapshot)
                        self.arrayPosts.add(dictionary)
                    }
                }

                self.arrayPosts.sorted { (p1, p2) -> Bool in
                    // declare post type

                    var postDate1:NSNumber!
                    var postDate2:NSNumber!
                    // check the object type and get the date value to compare.
                    if p1 is photoPost {
                        let obj:photoPost =  p1 as! photoPost
                        postDate1 =   obj.postDate
                    }
                    if p2 is photoPost {
                        let obj:photoPost =  p1 as! photoPost
                        postDate2 =   obj.postDate
                    }

                    if p1 is videoPost {
                        let obj:videoPost =  p1 as! videoPost
                        postDate1 =   obj.postDate
                    }
                    if p2 is videoPost {
                        let obj:videoPost =  p1 as! videoPost
                        postDate2 =   obj.postDate
                    }

                    return postDate1?.compare(postDate2!) == .orderedDescending
                }


                // use arrayPosts to show data on collection view
                self.newsfeedCollectionView?.reloadData()

            })

        })

    }
```

Comment: The way I would approach this is to turn it into a homogeneous array. Create a model that can be used to hold both photo posts and video posts and a date. Maybe a Date and an Enum. That way you don’t need to worry about solving this problem at all. I can add an answer later. Just not right now.

Comment: Are you able to show me an example please. I'm still fairly new to coding so trying to learn as I go @Fogmeister

Comment: @Pushpendra I updated my code so you can see what I have done so far

Comment: ok  no worries @Fogmeister I'll wait for your answer. Thanks

Comment: A couple of code review tips for you. Class names `videoPost` begin with an uppercase letter... `VideoPost`. And don’t use NSString, NSArray, NSDictionary, NSNumber, NSDate, etc... with Swift. Drop the NS from them. They are different types written for Swift.

Comment: Ok I will keep that in mind. Thanks @Fogmeister

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'd create a type that can hold any type of timeline post. In your question you have a `VideoPost` and a `PhotoPost` so we need a type that can hold either a video or a photo and a date so that we can sort it.

You could add additional properties like comments, descriptions, likes, etc... if you need those too.

```
struct TimelinePost {
    enum Content {
        case photo(UIImage)
        case video(URL) // I don't know how you are storing videos but I'm using URL here as an example
    }

    let date: Date
    let content: Content
}
```

By doing this you remove the need to have a heterogeneous array. It is always a good idea to try and work with homogeneous data if possible. As you have found out, it can get tricky to work with heterogeneous data.

Now you can make it comparable...

```
extension TimelinePost: Comparable {
    static func < (lhs: TimelinePost, rhs: TimelinePost) -> Bool {
        return lhs.date < rhs.date
    }

    static func == (lhs: TimelinePost, rhs: TimelinePost) -> Bool {
        return lhs.date == rhs.date // this is probably to correct.
        // you need to decide what it means for two posts to be equal.
    }
}
```

That takes care of sorting the array.

Now you can convert your arrays like this...

```
let videoArray = ... // your video array
let photoArray = ... // your photo array

let timelineArray: [TimelinePost] = 
    (videoArray.map { TimelinePost(date: $0.date, content: .video($0.url)) }
    + photoArray.map { TimelinePost(date: $0.date, content: .photo($0.image)) })
    .sorted()
```

You might want to make this into a function or change the logic here... up to you.

Now `timelineArray` is an array of structs (`TimelinePost`) sorted in date order. It contains all your videos and photos.

You could even add an extension to provide the `UICollectionViewCell` reuse identifier to it...

```
extension TimelinePost {
    var reuseIdentifier: String {
        switch content {
        case .photo:
            return "PhotoCell"
        case .video:
            return "VideoCell"
        }
    }
}
```

To get the reuse identifier in `cellForItem` (for your collection view) you just do something like...

```
let timelinePost = timelineArray[indexPath.item]
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: timelinePost.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
```

Comment: I get an error: Type 'TimelinePost' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable' from the line `extension TimelinePost: Comparable {`

Comment: @j.iese ah, I forgot to add the == function

Comment: I did `let videoArray = [videoPost]()` but then I get an error: Cannot use instance member 'videoArray' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available. on the line `(videoArray.map { ...`

Comment: @j.iese oh yeah. You can’t use properties within other properties. You need to go back to the Swift basics. Learn how the basics work. There is a free book from Apple. You should read that.